# Flutter: fully include a ListView inside a Column (no Expanded)

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Inside a scroll view I want to display a widget, then a list, then a widget. Something among the lines of:

```dart
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Text("Top of ListView"),
          ListView.builder(
              itemCount: 100,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) => Text('Line $index')),
          Text("Below of ListView")
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Where the content of the `SingleChildScrollView` would be:

```dart
Text("Top of ListView"),
Text('Line 0'),
Text('Line 1'),
...
Text('Line 98'),
Text('Line 99'),
Text("Bottom of ListView")
```

Of course this code doesn't work, since ListView height is undefined. Wrapping the `ListView` with `Expanded` isn't the solution since I want `Text("Top of ListView")` to disappear when I begin to scroll and `Text("Bottom of ListView")` to appear only when reaching bottom (as if they are the first item and the last item of the list, respectively).

My ideas:

- Putting `Text("Top of ListView")` and `Text("Bottom of ListView")`
  inside the `ListView` : easy to do for this example, but in real world there won't be only one widget in front of or behind the list. Messy and hard to maintain.
- Adding the list items to the `Column` directly : aka re-implementing `ListView`.
- Wrapping `ListView` into a `Container` with a fixed height corresponding to the calculated `ListView` height: I don't know how to measure childrens.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use `CustomScrollView` to achieve this:

```dart
CustomScrollView(
  slivers: [
    SliverList(
      delegate: SliverChildListDelegate([Text("Top of ListView")]),
    ),
    SliverList(
      delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
        (context, index) => Text('Line $index')
        childCount: 100,
      ),
    ),
    SliverList(
      delegate: SliverChildListDelegate([Text("Below of ListView")]),
    ),
  ],
),
```

Comment: It solve the problem ... except I was using `ListView.separated` instead of `ListView.builder`. I will open a new question for `SliverChildBuilderDelegate` with separators.